# Py2dsc, is it possible to use another name than setup.py for py2dsc?

Tags: python, linux, debian

I am trying to build a python debian package. 
it is cross platform, so for windows I use setup.py, for linux I use setuplinux.py.

My question is how to use py2dsc with setuplinux.py?
It seems py2dsc just call setup.py. Thanks.